# Why is my mutual friends query so slow?

Tags: mysql

This query used to run very quickly when my database only had a finite amount of friends in it, however as the user base has grown I've found the query getting exponentially slower.

The schema for my friends table looks like:

```
friend_id   -   entity_id1  -   entity_id2   -   category 
    1               1                2               1
    2               2                1               1
    3               3                2               1
    4               2                3               1
    5               1                3               1
    6               3                1               1
```

As we can see above, there is a reciprocal relationship between each friend association, this was implemented to improve the query time for suggested friends.

I am now trying to return mutual friends in my suggested friends payload, however the query takes around 1 second to compile for each user in a while loop, and I only currently have 2000 users...this will be a huge problem as the application scales further.

The query I am currently using is as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS mutual_count
FROM entity
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM friends
    WHERE friends.Entity_Id1 = :friendId AND friends.Category <> 4
      AND friends.Entity_Id2 = entity.Entity_Id
  )
  AND EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM friends
    WHERE friends.Entity_Id1 = :userId AND friends.Category <> 4
      AND friends.Entity_Id2 = entity.Entity_Id
  )
```

Where :userId is the logged in user and :friendId is the user we want to get the mutual friends of.  As I said, this query works fine but its extremely slow, how can I optimise it?

Comment: What indexes are you using for columns: entity_id1, entity_id2 and category ?

Comment: sorry updated my question, friend_id is the primary key, entity_id1 and entity_id2 are foreign keys to the entity table

Comment: You should `EXPLAIN` it.

Comment: Ok those are the keys, but what kind of index do each column use? A hash index, b-tree index, or none?

Comment: Ahh sorry, there are currently no indexes on each column

Comment: `ALTER TABLE friends ADD KEY (Entity_Id1 ,Category ,Entity_Id2 )` Whats the speed after you add this index?

Comment: I will try running that in a moment, what exactly does this do though? I dont want to damage my schema (not looked at indexing before)

Comment: Just add a composite index which will speed up your query.It can be dropped at any time,dont worry

Comment: wow...adding the index improved the speed from 1.45345 sec to 0.000005 sec, however I notice on the first run of the query for that user it will still take anywhere between 0.9998 and 1.45543 sec to compile, the index is essentially cacheing that result for future?

Comment: which means, the first query over 20 results would take 20 seconds still, but future queries on the same result set would take ~0.0001 sec

Comment: It shoudnt need to compile anything this is quite strange.

Comment: It may just be the phpmyadmin workbench varying on speed, seems fast when I make an API call from postman.

Comment: @Mihai if youd like to post an answer I'll accept, that has fixed the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there are 2 correlated subqueries which are the fastest queries you can get in mysql, the best index for both subqueries is this one:

```
ALTER TABLE friends ADD KEY (Entity_Id1, Category, Entity_Id2)
```

Comment: I have a question about this, is it bad practice to put a key on every table in my database, is this a sensible thing to do? I only wonder because the speed increase is so significant in this case

Comment: @Alex In general indexes speed up SELECTS and slow down INSERT and UPDATES.As a rule avoid premature indexing,index only the most common run queries and those critical to the application.Indexes eat memory and if you index everything most likely you`ll run into issues.

Answer (score 1):

You have two heavy subqueries and You selects all columns in both of them. 
First eliminate one of them - try that:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS mutual_count
FROM entity
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*) > 0
    FROM friends
    WHERE friends.Category <> 4 AND friends.Entity_Id2 = entity.Entity_Id
        AND (friends.Entity_Id1 = :friendId AND friends.Entity_Id1 = :userId)
)
```

Then I suggest inner join instead of subquery - maybe something like that:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT entity.id) AS mutual_count
FROM entity
INNER JOIN friends ON friends.Entity_Id2 = entity.Entity_Id
    AND friends.Category <> 4
    AND (friends.Entity_Id1 = :userId AND friends.Entity_Id1 = :friendId)
```

I haven't checked it (and I don't know tables structure) so there may be some syntax error - but I hope It will help You somehow.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however the count being returned is wrong, maybe due to the bi-directional relationshipo?

Comment: my mistake (just edited my answer) - instead of 'OR' use 'AND' since both conditions must be true

Comment: Thanks Adam this worked too, however Mihai's solution was faster :)